# Web page speed not increasing

Tags: javascript, html, .htaccess, cdn, keep-alive

I optimize my site and test my site with great online tool 
http://www.webpagetest.org/result/131010_3K_ZE6/1/performance_optimization/#first_byte_time

but here i see my setting is not work, but some online tool accept my setting,

50% online speed checket tools show that my site keep alive is on, 
but 50% online speed tools show that keep alive is not set,

as show in image, 2nd column, on all css and js, keep alive is on, but on some images keep alive is on, and on some images keep alive is off, please tell me why keep alive is not set on some images?

here is my .htaccess file code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase / 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 

    <IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/plain "access 1 month"

    ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-icon "access 1 year"
</IfModule>
```

.

```
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Connection keep-alive
</ifModule>

<FilesMatch ".(ttf|otf|eot|woff)$">
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

As you see in snap shoot column 4, some images is compress and some not, ,, what can i do to compress all images?

.

In last column, you see all CDN is fail, 
but i use subdomin to load css,js,swf files,

i create new subdomin with name cdn.domain.com, and set it to my include folder path.
all css/js and swf files are there,

and i update src code

```
eg.1 cdn.domin.com/css/style.css
eg.2 cdn.domin.com/js/script.js
```

What i do rong? in column 1 you see css/js is load with subdomin name, but CDN column says CDN is not set.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. In HTTP/1.1, keep-alive is default to open, the error in the test result maybe by the images which are too big to cause the alive connection timeout.

2.CDN is not a file in the domain including "cdn", it's a network server technology, take a look on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network